# Solve an equation involving fractional powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

doing some BASIC programming, and have this exponential equation that works perfectly:

Constants: $K=10,A=64,B=1023,D=1000$

The real variable input is $C\in[0,D]$

I have $Y=A+(B-A)\cdot\frac{K^{1-\frac{C}{D}}-1}{K-1}$

Now I want to go the other way: $C=$?

I've come as far as $(Y-A)\cdot\frac{K-1}{B-A}=K^{1-\frac{C}{D}-1}$

But my math skills is no longer quite as good as back in school days...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides and use the rule $\log a^b=b\log a$. (In your last equation, on the left hand side, you want $ ((Y-A)(K-1)/(B\color\red{-A}))$, I think.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $Z=\frac{(Y-A)(K-1)}{B-A}+1$, we have
$$\begin{align}Z=K^{1-(C/D)}&\iff \frac ZK=K^{-C/D}\\&\iff \log_K(Z/K)=\log_KK^{-C/D}\\&\iff \log_K(Z)-1=-C/D\\&\iff C=D-D\log_K(Z).\end{align}$$
Hence, the answer is
$$C=D-D\log_K\left\{\frac{(Y-A)(K-1)}{B-A}+1\right\}.$$

Here, I used $\log_aa^b=b,\log_a(ab)=\log_aa+\log_ab=1+\log_ab$.

Comment: Thanks I'll test this out tomorrow. But (1-C/D)-1 would be correct as ( C/D ) must range from 0 - 1 (D=1000).

Comment: @EGK: (1-C/D)-1=C/D? Is it (1-C/D)-1=-C/D, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, (1-C/D)-1 = -C/D, which is not the same as    ((1−C)/D)−1. This verified by testing with C=2 and D=3..The last equation gives a different result than the first two

Comment: @EGK: I edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: No still something wrong. I just tested it in software, and for the given inputs the resulting Y should be 500, instead it was -2549.616.        This is the actual code:  U  = -Slider1.Maximum * Log(K^(          ((GraphYmax-SliderMin) * (K-1)) / (SliderMax-SliderMin))       )

Comment: The first equation you wrote is Y = A + ( B - A ) * ( K ^ (  1 - C / D ) - 1 ) / ( K - 1 ). My understanding is $$Y=A+\frac{(B-A)(K^{1-(C/D)}-1)}{K-1}.$$ Correct?

Comment: @EGK: If my understanding written in the above my comment is correct, the answer should be what I wrote in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Well, since I think in a programmer's way we may have a parenthesis problem. To clarify here is the actual ok running code that I want to solve for C:    A=SliderMin // = 64
  B=SliderMax // = 1023
  C=Slider1.Value // Range 0 - 1000
  D=Slider1.Maximum // = 1000
  
  // Intermediates:
  R = 1 - C / D
  S = ( K ^ R ) - 1 
  T = K - 1
  
  GraphYmax = A + S * ( B - A ) / T

Comment: A=SliderMin // = 64
  B=SliderMax // = 1023
  C=Slider1.Value // Range 0 - 1000
  D=Slider1.Maximum // = 1000
  
  // Intermediates:
  R = 1 - C / D
  S = ( K ^ R ) - 1 
  T = K - 1
  
  GraphYmax = A + S * ( B - A ) / T

Comment: The way you write is very difficult for me to get the meaning because you don't use any comma, though my understanding seems correct.

Comment: TestingTestingTesting